# I am new to apache solr, and working on a package. The index created by solr has only .CFS, .gen, insegmentparents file, and .del file

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

I know it contains header and file data in raw format, but does this mean everytime i query the index, the raw data is processed to find out the frequency of terms? Since I cannot see a .frq file? Is there any way to find out how the data is stored in .cfs file?

Answer (score 0):

The Index file format is [Compound](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_0/fileformats.html#Compound%20Files) and hence the cfs file created which has all the files combined.

Check  [File Format](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_0/fileformats.html) which will give a detail for Lucene Index file formats.

You can use [Luke](http://www.getopt.org/luke/) to explore your Lucene Index files.

Comment: Thanks @jayendra , but Luke has support only till lucene codecspostings40(lucene ver4.0), not beyond that. Btw, I tried opening it with vim editor and found a rough idea of the order of storing.

Comment: one more thing, does the solr search through strings only since multimapsolrparams has only a map<string string[]> does this automatically insert double fields that I wish to query upon?